# Android webview, pretend file drop

Tags: java, javascript, android, jquery, http

Imagine I have a jQuery script to listen for drag and drop action and then upload them. If I open my webpage in a `WebView` , how can I drop a `File` object into that area? (basically fake a drop given I have a `File` object or path to that `File`

for example I use the camera to take a picture, then I save that image. Now I would like to upload that image purely using browser capabilities (without httpClient requests on android side). Or If I could add my file to a file upload `input` (which I couldn't find a way to achieve).

Comment: First of all, how would you drag and drop an image from Gallery Activity to the Browser's WebView activity? -_-

Comment: As I said **fake** a drop. i.e. make jQuery think it's a drop but it's actually not a drop. Or allow jQuery to capture the `File` in another way. The main question is how to pass `File` from my android side to jQuery?